# plt.bar or ax.bar can not change color when I set the certain parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I tried to change the color for my bar plot, and I passed the correct parameter for `color = "red"` or some other color. The problem is that no matter what I changed, the bar color is always black. I don't know what's going on.

I tried to use `plt.plot` and `ax.plot`, but they are the same. I still can not change the color.

[image: current output]

Comment: I guess the borders are black, and we can only see the borders because the bars are so dense. Try adding `edgecolor='none'`

Comment: Or `edgcolor='deeppink'`